# What is the last day of an ISO date range like 1970--1979?

Tags: date, range, iso8601

I'm not sure if the first day of `1970--1979` is `1970-01-01` and the last day is `1979-12-31`.

A quick search on Google didn't throw up the answer. Most examples would give a range such as `1970-01-01--1979-12-31` which although unambiguous, is clunkier than `1970--1979` and due to the extra detail, more prone to errors.

Comment: Could you clarify *exactly* what you mean by "ISO date range"? ISO-8601 doesn't define ranges like this, as far as I can see.

Comment: I think the ISO term is "interval" not "range." However, I have found out more - see below.

Comment: Looking through ISO-8601 I still see no indication that "1970--1979" is a representation of a time interval. In particular, 4.4.2 specifies that the separator between a start and an end must be a solidus (/).

Comment: @Jon - I don't have access to the actual standard so I am quoting from secondary sources. Wikipedia says

Comment: Oops. I meant to say: @Jon - I don't have access to the actual standard so I am quoting from secondary sources. Wikipedia (ISO 8601) says <<Section 4.4.2 of the standard notes that: "In certain application areas a double hyphen is used as a separator instead of a solidus.">> I prefer a double hyphen as it avoid filesystem problems, and it also suggests a range rather than an alternative (as in "and/or"). I wonder if the double hyphen was in an earlier edition of the standard. At any rate, if you have access, perhaps you could check section 4.4.2?

Comment: Aha, yes - it has that as a small note. There are no examples of using that, which is why I didn't find it. But it does also state in 4.4.4.1: "When the application identifies the need for a complete representation of a time interval, identified by its start and its end, it shall use an expression in accordance with 4.4.2 combining any two complete date and time of day representations as defined in 4.3.2, provided that the resulting expression is either consistently in basic
format or consistently in extended format." 1970 isn't a *complete* date and time of day reprsentation.

Comment: Section 4.4.5 talks about "representations other than complete" and in particular mentions omitting "higher order time elements", e.g. missing out the year/month from the end point if it's the same as the start point.

Comment: It's possible that other parts of section 4.4.5 are intended to allow representations such as 1970--1979, but if so, they don't indicate the meaning. I would personally expect it to mean "until the final moment in 1979" but the standard doesn't state that clearly as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Jon - That comment about "complete" date and time elements makes this unworkable. Even if you gave a time complete to a second, the interval would not include the final second. And it would be unreasonably long in text. However, thanks for taking the trouble to look this up and post it.

Answer (score 1):

In "A summary of the international standard date and time notation," Markus Kuhn [1](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/iso-time.html) writes:

> ISO 8601 does not specify, whether its notations specify a point in
>   time or a time period. This means for example that ISO 8601 does not
>   define whether 09:00 refers to the exact end of the ninth hour of the
>   day or the period from 09:00 to 09:01 or anything else. The users of
>   the standard must somehow agree on the exact interpretation of the
>   time notation if this should be of any concern.

So to answer my own question, the last day of 1970--1979 is 1979-12-31 if I say that is the interpretation that I intend. Which it is!

I find ISO's lack of specification ... disturbing.

Comment: I beg to differ. The lack of specification is pragmatic. The parties exchanging data like `09:00` or `1970--1979` know a lot better what they mean than some ISO committee does. And you’re free to give the exact dates if you prefer. Thanks for the informative answer to your own question, it’s appreciated.